# delete script folder of python projects

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using Pycharm IDE for my python projects. When I try to send my projects by email it gets blocked for security issues but, when I delete the script folder in my projects it is sent. But, will it run in the destination computer correctly without the script folder?
Thank you for your help

Comment: Script folder is specifically for your machine and you can install back all again if you have requirement.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as systems have same version of python running and fully functional code without any missing dependencies, it'll run file.
All you need is python file and associated data to run it successfully on any system.

Answer (score 0):

Allow users to manage their access to less secure apps :
You may be able to connect to the Gmail server with your Google username and password. This setup is only available when:
You have enabled the option to allow access to less secure apps in the Google account that you use to connect to the Gmail service.
You have not enabled 2-Step Verification for this Google account.

If you have enabled 2-Step Verification for this Google account, you need to generate and use an App Password. Configure the SMTP settings in Hub as if access to less secure apps were disabled.